# state hooks don't update from useEffect function calls

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

In useEffect I call getPins which queries a DB for pins. I am then looping through the pins and and trying to decrease 'pinsRemaining' which is a state hook.

In state it shows that the hook decreases, but it's not working in the code. When I console log pinsRemaining from getPinnedLocations() its always the same number.

The interesting thing is that if I make 'pinsRemaining' a const varaible (not state hook) it does work to decrease the counter, but that creates other problems.

I'm not sure how to get this code to work. I've read about how state hooks are async here

[useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

I've tried just adding an empty useEffect hook like this but it doesn't work

```
 useEffect(() => {}, [pinsRemaining])
```

Maybe I need to be doing something inside of this?

Here is my full code.

```
const [pinsRemaining, setPinsRemaining] = useState(5)


  useEffect(() => {

    if (isLoggedIn && user !== {}) {

      APIService.getAccountById(
        Number(id)
      ).then(_user => {
        setUser(_user)
        getPins(_user)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log("error", err)
      })

    } 

  }, []);

  const getPins = (_user) => {
    APIService.getPinsForUser(_user.id).then(pins => {

      pins.map(pin => {


        pushPinnedLocation(pin.location_id, _user)
      })
    })
    
  }

   const pushPinnedLocation = (location, date, _user) => {

//decrementing in hook doesn't work here
  setPinsRemaining((prevState)=> prevState - 1)

//but decrementing with var does
    pins = pins - 1

    console.log("state hook", pinsRemaining)
    console.log("const var", pins)


    setLocationDateMap(new Map(locationDateMap.set(location, date)))

if(pinsRemaining === 0){
    getMatchesFromDB(_user)
}
  
  }


const getMatchesFromDB = (_user) => {
 
    let pinsArray = Array.from(locationDateMap)
    pinsArray.map(obj => {
      let location = obj[0]
      let date = obj[1]
      let locationDate = date + "-" + location
   
      let dbMatches;

      let params = {
        location_date_id: locationDate, 
        user_id: _user.id, 
        seeking: _user.seeking
      }
      APIService.getMatchesByLocationDateId(params).then(data => {

       dbMatches = data.map((match, i) => {
        

        if(match.likes_recieved && match.likes_sent 
          && match.likes_recieved.includes(_user.id + "")
          && match.likes_sent.includes(_user.id + "")){

          match.connectedStatus = 3
          
        }else if(match.likes_recieved && match.likes_recieved.includes(_user.id + "")){
          match.connectedStatus = 2
        }else if(match.likes_sent && match.likes_sent.includes(_user.id + "")){
          match.connectedStatus = 1
        }else{
          match.connectedStatus = 0
        }

        match.name = match.user_name
         return match
       })


      }).then(() => {

        setMatches(matches => [...matches, ...dbMatches]);
      })

    })
  
}
```

Comment: Try to do it this way `setPinsRemaining((prevState)=> prevState - 1)`

Comment: Unfortunately I had tried that before, I think it is the better way but still no luck. It decreases the counter in state, but not when I console.log from the function, so the timing is still off somehow

Comment: Where do you call your console.log() ? Where you call your log might not be the current state. You need to use some useEffect(()=>, [pinsRemaining]) to react to the state change

Comment: I'm logging from pushPinnedLocation(). So can useEffect(()=> [pinsRemaining] be left empty and it will update the state?